# Все ли операции, зависимые на ответ, должны быть синхронны?

Tags: javascript, сервер, express

К примеру программа отослала запрос на сервер и ждет от него ответа. На сервере же имеется асинхронная функция чтения. В этом случае ответ будет получен 2 раза или 3 раза? Сначала ответ с пустой строкой, а затем еще 1 ответ с содержимым прочитанного файла? или же сначала ответ с пустой строкой, затем ответ с содержимым прочитанного файла и затем ответ 
с пустой строкой???

Пример:

```
https.createServer((req, res) => {
    req.on("data", data => {
        fs.readFile("./123.txt", "utf8", (err, data)=>{
            if(!err){
                 res.end(data);
            }
        }
    }
res.end("");
});
```

Comment: после первого res.end больше ничего не будет получено

Comment: Спасибо. Осталось понять как синхронно записывать с проверкой на занятость для записи... А то в интернете в основном асинхронные примеры. А синхронных примеров с open и close нет, а то что есть не совсем корректно работают...(с предупреждениями)....

Comment: И правильно предупреждают. Научитесь работать с асинхронным кодом. Не используйте синхронные методы, особенно в обработчиках запросов.

Comment: Так примеров то нет. если я res.end помещаю в callback асинхронной функции записи или чтения генерируется ошибка того что ответ получен раньше чем закрывается поток, а если же я помешу res.end за callback тогда ответ сработает еще до того как функция что то запишет или вернет. Поэтому на серверной части я так полагаю нужно все писать синхронно. но как сделать так, что бы он еще и проверял файл на занятость другими устройствами, как это сделано почти в большинстве других компилируемых ЯП я не знаю...

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, должно быть у синхронной функции что то на подобии метода join, как в плюсах. Метод который заставляет текущий поток ожидать в конкретном месте, пока другой поток не завершит свою работу. что то наподобии. В общем я не знаю и хотел спросить как люди решают вопрос на стороне сервера. ?

Comment: Подождите, вы все смешали в кучу. И доступ к файлу и синхронность и разные устройства еще какие-то. Выдохните и делайте по небольшим шагам. Сначала решите и подробно опишите, что вам надо и что вы хотите.

Comment: К тому же, имей в виду, что node.js - он однопоточный. Если у вас доступ к файлу только с одного инстанса\сервера то конфликтов записи не может быть!

Comment: О том, что он однопоточный я конечно слышал, но не думал, что это правда, так как визуально асинхронная функция выглядит как другой поток. Только не давно я стал подозревать что это не другой поток а один, когда алерт заблокировал все мои асинхронные функции... Ну ладно не суть. Хорошо, а если 2 клиента одновременно отсылают запрос и получается 1 клиент будет ожидать пока не обработается запрос другого, но люди говорят что по сути порт может сколько угодно делать подключений... Просто нельзя ответить на один вопрос не затронув другие...

Comment: Получается что клиенты при отправке запросов на сервер попадают в некую очередь, которая будет уменьшаться по мере выполнения сервером алгоритма для конкретного клиента? Правильно я понимаю?